# python nested list and string trimming in a for statement

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

Now, having a list of lists with 2 strings:

```
l1 = [['a', 'www.apple.com/a www.google.com www.yahoo.com'],
    ['b', 'www.apple.com/sm www.sashgh.com www.uensg.com'],
    ['c', 'www.apple.com/oths www.zhiut.com'],
    ['d', 'www.amazon.com www.toronto.com']]
```

I want to keep the first string, and get the 'apple.com' url in the 2nd string or if there is not 'apple.com' give a None (like the case in 'd'):

```
l2 = [['a', 'www.apple.com/a'], 
    ['b', 'www.apple.com/sm'],
    ['c', 'www.apple.com/oths'],
    ['d', None]]
```

I tried this :

```
l2 = []
for l in l1:
    for url in l[1].split(' '):
        if 'apple.com' in url:
            l2.append([l[0], url])
            break
        else:
            l2.append([l[0], None])
            break
```

and the code now worked!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "very bad"?

Comment: Your inner loop should be `for url in l[1].split(' ')` (not `l1[1]`), and similarly in the `append` statements. As it stands you will get a lot of entries in `l2` with `None` second entry - you'd need a flag to check for any `l2` entries against a given `l1` and a final action.  I do also recommend NOT using using `l` as a variable name.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks, I got the code wrong, but it was 1 step to success

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for the advice! What would you use for a list? in my case, the element in the outer list is also list, thus I use `l`

Comment: @RichardFan "list" is the structure. The name would be better if it describes the contents. Note that your update in the question would only work for cases where "apple.com" occurs in the first space-separated element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only appending the first `apple.com` in the split strings in the second elements of the sublists, you could use `next` and a generator expression to extract the first `apple.com`s.

```
out = [[first, next((s for s in second.split() if 'apple.com' in s), None)] for first, second in l1]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'www.apple.com/a'],
 ['b', 'www.apple.com/sm'],
 ['c', 'www.apple.com/oths'],
 ['d', None]]
```